# WeakReference in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, weak-references

I want to use the `WeakReference` approach to not leak memory with my `AsyncTask`. I found examples online and on Stackoverflow, but they only get the reference in `onPostExecute` and I am unsure how to correctly use it in all 3 of the UI methods.
My current approach is like this, but I have no clue if I can get rid of some redundancy. Why can't I just call `activityReference.get()` in the constructor and then only check for null in each of the UI methods? Why do the examples online call `get` right before using the `WeakReference`?

```
private static class ExampleAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> {
    private WeakReference<MainActivity> activityReference;

    ExampleAsyncTask(MainActivity context) {
        activityReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        MainActivity activity = activityReference.get();
        if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing()) {
            return;
        }

        activity.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
        for (int i = 1; i < integers[0]; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            publishProgress((i * 100) / integers[0]);
        }

        return "Finished";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        MainActivity activity = activityReference.get();
        if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing()) {
            return;
        }

        activity.progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        MainActivity activity = activityReference.get();
        if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing()) {
            return;
        }

        activity.progressBar.setProgress(0);
        activity.progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Toast.makeText(activity, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check for null in `WeakReference` everytime you need to use it is necessary because the GC process can clear the instance anytime during your work. Besides, `onPreExecute`, `onPostExecute` and `doInBackground` is run in the different thread, there is also some delay when changing thread and the instance may be cleared in between too.

I have a helper method that does the check for null in `WeakReference` and its instance. Use it if you like:

```
public <T> T getInstance(WeakReference<T> weakReference) {
    if (weakReference == null || weakReference.get() == null)
        return null;

    // Do more check for your activity if need

    return weakReference.get();
}
```